# Not able to decode inputStream received from restful service to Bitmap in Android

Tags: java, android, image, rest

I have a requirement of sending image from android client to Restful Web Service on a button click, for which I used the following code

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myImage);  
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
reqParams.put("image",encodedString);
client.post(IMAGE_POST_URL, reqParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {....});
```

I am able to send the image to the restful service and save it in MySql DB as Blob type.
Upon clicking another button I am receiving the image from restful web service as InputStream. But I am not able to convert to Bitmap and display on the screen using following code. Could someone light me up on where I am doing wrong.

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
imgView.setImageBitmap(imageBmp);
```

Any help is appreciated..

Here is the Rest service methods I am using ..

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadImage1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response uploadImage1(@FormParam(value = "image") String image) {     
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getBytes());
.....(MySQL Code to insert as BLOB)}

@GET
@Path("/getImage")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getImage() {....
Response.ok(blob.getBinaryStream(), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();}
```

Comment: Are you sure the bitmap is valid once you retrieve it from the DB ? Could you check this on server-side ?

Comment: Ya.. I decoded on the server side and checked if I am able to open the image.... It was showing the image properly

Comment: Are you sending the raw bytes, or as a Base64 encoded String ?

Comment: At what point are you performing the required Base-64 decoding? At any point?

Comment: I am sending from Android, as a Base64 encoded String by putting in the requestParam. I am receiving whatever I sent to backend in the form of inputStream using below...   Response.ok(blob.getBinaryStream(), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();

Comment: You haven't answered my question. When if ever are you *de*-coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answers to comments, it appears that you are never performing a base64 *decode* step. You need to do that somewhere: either

- at the point where you insert the Blob into the database, or
- when you retrieve the Blob and send it to the peer, or
- at the point where you receive it in the peer, before you turn it back into an image.

Comment: Decoding back to Base64 is what I was missing...so I added following line before decodeStream and it worked.   `Base64InputStream base64InputStream = new Base64InputStream(inputStream,Base64.DEFAULT);`   `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(base64InputStream);`